# Google Charts set default date range

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've created a dashboard with the Google Charts API that has a `DateRangeFilter` and a `ComboChart` with a data point for every Monday over 3 months. It contains an actual series (*which can be `null`*) as a bar graph, and a goal series that always has data associated with it.

Ideally, I would like to set the `DateRangeFilter` to show just the current and previous week, as well as 2 weeks ahead, but still allow me to manipulate the range filter to show additional data.

So far I've tried setting `hAxis.viewWindow.max` and `hAxis.viewWindow.min` to the correct dates, but this just crops the graph, and won't let me go back to the points that get cropped out.

**Dashboard setup:**

```js
var rangeFitter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
  'containerId': 'filter_div',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Closed Date'
  }
});

var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'ComboChart',
  'containerId': 'chart_div',
  'options': {
    animation: {
      duration: 500,
      startup: true,
      easing: 'out'
    },
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 4,
        units: {
          days: {
            format: ['MMYY']
          }

        }
      },
      //this crops the graph :c
      viewWindow: {
        min: new Date(2016, 0, 11),
        max: new Date(2016, 2, 7)
      }
    },
    'height': 300,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true,
      trigger: 'selection'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      0: {
        targetAxisIndex: 0
      },

      1: {
        type: 'line',
        pointSize: 5
      }
    }
  }
});

dashboard.bind(rangeFilter, lineChart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. I was searching for something within the chart options, but it turns out the DateRangeFilter control has a "state" parameter. Here it is implemented in my example

```
 var rangeFliter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                    'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
                    'containerId': 'filter_div',
                    'options': {
                        'filterColumnLabel': 'Closed Date'  
                    },
                    //this will set the default range based on the values you provide
                    'state': {'lowValue': new Date(2016, 0, 11), 'highValue': new Date(2016, 1, 1)}
                });
```